# Can't remove underline of linkbutton

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

In my webform I have a linkbutton defined as....

```
<asp:LinkButton Visible="True" style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;" Font-Underline="false" runat="server" ID="lnkEditCarOrderNumber" 
    CommandName="EditCarDetails"><%#((int)Eval("CarStatusId")!=1 && (Eval("CarOrderNumber")=="" || Eval("CarOrderNumber")==DBNull.Value)) 
    ? "(click to add)" 
    Eval("CarOrderNumber")%>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

The text is dynamic, created from the C# ternary expression.

As you can see I tried to remove the underline in both style and Font-Underline. But the link always shows an underline. Any idea why?

I know I can try CSS, but using inline style should work too. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that was generated by the code? Otherwise it's hard to say

Comment: Have you tried putting "!important" after "none"?
`text-decoration: none !important`

Comment: @Kjvhout beat me to it. Try his suggestion. It's very possible something is overriding it.

Comment: Thanks! !important fixed it. So, I guess it was a conflict. @Kjvhout if you pull your response out of the comment I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I just did, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

Some more information about "!important":
https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

I would remove

```
Font-Underline="false"
```

and use

```
CssClass="nounderlineline" //use your own css class or create one.
```

This works on my sites and I use LinkButtons a lot. Should work for you too.